# Numpy Interpolation Between Points Within Array (scipy.griddata)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have a numpy array of a fixed size holding irregularly spaced data. An example would be:

```
[1 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 2 0
 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0
 0 1 0 0 1 0 6 0 9 0
 0 0 0 0 6 0 3 0 0 1]
```

I want to keep the array the same shape, but have all the 0 values overwritten with data interpolated from the points that do have data. If the data points in the array are thought of as height values, this would essentially be creating a surface over the points.

I have been trying to use `scipy.interpolate.griddata` but am continually getting errors. I start with an array of my known data points, as [x, y, value]. For the above, (first row only for brevity)

```
data = [0, 0, 1
        0, 3, 3
        0, 8, 2 ....................
```

I then define

```
points = (data[:,0], data[:,1])
values = (data[:,2])
```

Next, I define the points to sample at (in this case, the grid I desire)

```
grid = np.indices((4,10))
```

Finally, call griddata

```
t = interpolate.griddata(points, values, grid, method = 'linear')
```

This returns the following error

```
ValueError: number of dimensions in xi does not match x
```

Am I using the wrong function?

Thanks!

Comment: I just helped someone else with `interp2d`.  That might fit your case, fitting a regular grid to scattered data points.  In any case, when using these functions, pay close attention to the required dimensions and shapes of the arguments, both the source data and the interpolation points.  Understanding the documentation is critical.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: You need to pass the desired points as a tuple

```
t = interpolate.griddata(points, values, (grid[0,:,:], grid[1,:,:]), method = 'linear')
```